# Filling a Partially Rounded Rectangle with GDI+

Tags: c++, mfc, drawing, gdi+

I have a rounded rectangle that I make like so

```
dc.RoundRect(textBorder, CPoint(20, 20));
```

Later on I draw a line through it about 1/3 of the way down.

```
dc.LineTo(textBorder.right, textBorder.top + 15);
```

Now I would like to fill just the part above the line with a solid color.  In other words I need to fill a partially rounded rectangle, because the top of the rectangle is rounded, but the bottom of it is truncated by the line.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you  tried using a combination of [CreateRoundRectRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf6xz5t9.aspx) and then [FillRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6df5dz8f.aspx) to fill the non-rectangular area?

This the example given in the docs for CreateRoundRectRegion:

```
CRgn   rgnA, rgnB, rgnC;

VERIFY(rgnA.CreateRoundRectRgn( 50, 50, 150, 150, 30, 30 ));
VERIFY(rgnB.CreateRoundRectRgn( 200, 75, 250, 125, 50, 50 ));
VERIFY(rgnC.CreateRectRgn( 0, 0, 50, 50 ));

int nCombineResult = rgnC.CombineRgn( &rgnA, &rgnB, RGN_OR );
ASSERT( nCombineResult != ERROR && nCombineResult != NULLREGION );

CBrush brA, brB, brC;
VERIFY(brA.CreateSolidBrush( RGB(255, 0, 0) ));  
VERIFY(pDC->FillRgn( &rgnA, &brA));      // rgnA Red Filled

VERIFY(brB.CreateSolidBrush( RGB(0, 255, 0) ));  
VERIFY(pDC->FillRgn( &rgnB, &brB));      // rgnB Green Filled
VERIFY(brC.CreateSolidBrush( RGB(0, 0, 255) ));  // rgnC Blue
VERIFY(pDC->FrameRgn( &rgnC, &brC, 2, 2 ));
```

In general, when you want to do something with non-rectangular areas you have to start looking into regions.

Comment: I haven't tried that but I don't see how that fixes my problem.  Won't that create rounded edges on the bottom of the region?

Comment: Now that you have edited it I see there is a CombineRgn function.  That might help.

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but the code is a little confusing. What you want to do is create a region that is the intersection of a regular rectangle with your rounded one.

Comment: Yeah, this code is directly from the documentation and is not meant to be a direct solution for the problem you're having.  Just a step on the path to getting you there.